# Wrap to new line in strategy comment

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How i can use two commands for Autoview in strategy comment? For example, i need to see in Autoview

- Command 1: position = c
- Command 2: buy

It's works, when I use alert comment for indicator

```
a=BINANCE c=position e=binancefutures s=FTMUSDT t=market
a=BINANCE b=buy e=binancefutures l=2 q=95% s=FTMUSDT t=market
```

but it's dosent work in strategy comment

```
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, when=Long, comment='a=BINANCE c=position e=binancefutures s=FTMUSDT t=market
a=BINANCE b=buy e=binancefutures l=2 q=95% s=FTMUSDT t=market')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\n` new line character to start a new line in your comment.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

if (close > open)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line")
if (close < open)
    strategy.close("Long", comment="First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line")
```

[image]